# How to automatically submit all forms with checked check_box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user is given the command "Choose 5 Inspirations"

A list of 20+ `inspirations` are shown.

There is a `check_box` on the top right hand corner of each inspirational panel.

```
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| 
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :check %>
    <%= inspiration.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  # How to make script where once a 5th check_box is checked then submit all forms with :check automatically?
  # Below is work in progress...
  $(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked').length;
    form.submit();
  })
</script>
```

What javascript is needed to make this work?

### UPDATE

**fast_track_one.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
  <% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'inspiration_ids[]', inspiration.id %>
    <%= inspiration.name %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="inspiration_ids[]"]', function() {
      var count = $('input[name="inspiration_ids[]"]:checked').length;
      if (count === 5) {
        $('#new_inspiration').trigger('submit.rails');
      }
    });
</script>
```

**inspirations_controller.rb**

```
class InspirationsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  before_action :set_inspiration, only: [:show, :like]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def fast_track_one
    @suggestions_user = User.find(1)
    @inspirations = @suggestions_user.inspirations
    if params[:inspiration_ids].present? && params[:inspiration_ids].size == 5
      @inspirations = Inspiration.where(id: params[:inspiration_ids])
      @inspirations.each do |inspiration|
        current_user.inspirations << inspiration
      end
    end
  end

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @inspirations = Inspiration.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @inspirations = current_user.inspirations.order("created_at DESC") if current_user.inspirations.present?
    end
  end

  def show
    @commentable = @inspiration
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @notable = @inspiration
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    if current_user
      @correct_user = current_user.inspirations.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      @correct_user = nil
    end
  end

  def new
    @suggestions_user = User.find(21) #1 in Development
    @inspirations = @suggestions_user.inspirations.top_6
    @maximum_length = Inspiration.validators_on( :name ).first.options[:maximum]
    existing_inspiration = Inspiration.find_by_id params[:inspiration_id]
    if existing_inspiration
      @inspiration = existing_inspiration.dup
    elsif params[:inspiration].try(:[], :name)
      @inspiration = Inspiration.new(inspiration_params) 
    else
      @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
    end
    respond_modal_with @inspiration
  end

  def edit
    @suggestions_user = User.find(21)
    @maximum_length = Inspiration.validators_on( :name ).first.options[:maximum]
    @inspirations = @suggestions_user.inspirations.order("created_at DESC")
    existing_inspiration = Inspiration.find_by_id params[:inspiration_id]
    if existing_inspiration
      @inspiration = existing_inspiration.dup
      @inspiration.image_file_name = existing_inspiration.image_file_name
    end
    respond_modal_with @inspiration
  end

  def create
    #@suggestions_user = User.find(21)
    #@inspirations = @suggestions_user.inspirations.order("created_at DESC")
    if current_user == nil
      # If there is no user, store the lifetime values to the session.
      session[:inspiration_name] = inspiration_params[:name]
      session[:inspiration_image] = inspiration_params[:image]
      redirect_to signup_path
    else
      #@inspiration.image_remote_url = params[:inspiration_image]
      @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build(inspiration_params)
      if @inspiration.conceal == true
        @inspiration.save
        if current_user.inspirations.count < 5
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          respond_modal_with @inspiration
        end
        flash[:info] = 'INSPIRATION SECRETLY SAVED. YOUR INSPIRATIONS ARE RANDOMIZED ON YOUR HOME PAGE TO GIVE YOU A FRESH SPARK OF INSPIRATION - EVERY TIME!'
      elsif
        @inspiration.save
        track_activity @inspiration
        if current_user.inspirations.count < 5
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          respond_modal_with @inspiration
        end
        flash[:info] = 'INSPIRATION SAVED. YOUR INSPIRATIONS ARE RANDOMIZED ON YOUR HOME PAGE TO GIVE YOU A FRESH SPARK OF INSPIRATION - EVERY TIME!'
      else
        respond_modal_with @inspiration
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    if @inspiration.update(inspiration_params)
      respond_modal_with @inspiration, location: root_path
      flash[:info] = 'INSPIRATION UPDATED'
    else
      respond_modal_with @inspiration
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @inspiration.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:alert] = 'INSPIRATION DELETED'
  end

  def like
    if current_user
      @inspiration_like = current_user.inspiration_likes.build(inspiration: @inspiration)
      if @inspiration_like.save
        @inspiration.increment!(:likes)
        flash[:info] = 'THANKS FOR LIKING!'
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'TWO MANY LIKES!'
      end  
        redirect_to(:back)
    else 
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:alert] = "PLEASE SIGN IN FIRST"
    end
  end

private

  def set_inspiration
    @inspiration = Inspiration.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to root_url unless @inspiration.user_id == current_user.id or @inspiration.conceal == false
  end

  def correct_user
    @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url, notice:  "NOT AUTHORIZED TO INSPIRATION" if @inspiration.nil?
  end

  def inspiration_params
    params.require(:inspiration).permit(:name, :image, :conceal, :tag_list, :content, :commentable, :comment, :like, :check, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at)
  end
end
```

Comment: The javascript required can be summarised as: `change` event handler on checkbox, `form.submit()` and `$('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked').length`

Comment: IMHO the UX is not that great as I am not left with the chance of reviewing my choices and may be change them before submitting. But yeah I have no idea of what your goals are!

Comment: Yes! bind an event of `change` get the `checked` checkboxes length and if gets to 5 then explicitly submit the form with `form.submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a rails form helper for a check box tag.

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
  <% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| 
    <%= check_box_tag 'inspiration_ids[]', inspiration.id %>
    <%= inspiration.name %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Access in the controller with:

```
if params[:inspiration_ids].present? && params[:inspiration_ids].size == 5
  @inspirations = Inspiration.where(id: params[:inspiration_ids])
  @inspirations.each do |inspiration|
    current_user.inspirations << inspiration
  end
end
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="inspiration_ids[]"]', function() {
  var count = $('input[name="inspiration_ids[]"]:checked').length;
  if (count === 5) {
    $('#new_inspiration').trigger('submit.rails');
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay it submits so that's a big step, but it only saves the first checked inspiration, not the other 4 of the pack.

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to figure out how to fix this error: `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: inspiration):`

Comment: This is what my params looks like: `def inspiration_params
    params.require(:inspiration).permit(:name, :image, :conceal, :tag_list, :content, :commentable, :comment, :like, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at)
  end`

Comment: I was also getting a `size` is `nil` answer so I put above it `if params[:inspiration_ids]` which got rid of that error. I also put your chunk of code in the controller method `def fast_track_one`.

Comment: I'm guessing the error was from passing `inspiration` to `create`, trying using the `<<` operator instead of create. I've updated the controller portion of the answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize this would be so tricky. Still getting the error `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: inspiration):` You sure it's `inspiration_ids` and not `id` or `ids` or `inspiration_id`? idk

Comment: Please post your current controller/view code. :) @AnthonyGalli.com

Comment: Posted the whole enchilada

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129987/discussion-between-codyeatworld-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked').length == 5) {
       $('form').submit(); // form should be selected as DOM element
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm checking the 5 boxes, but then nothing submits. I also tried by changing `form` to `.home-panels` and put the div class outside `<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| `

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code was as below:

```
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| # this line should be inside simple_form_for tag
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :check %>
    <%= inspiration.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which generate form multiple times, instead of your code replace below code which generates only one form with multiple checkboxes.

So here is the final code with JS. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
    <% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| 
        <%= f.check_box :check %>
        <%= inspiration.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked').length == 5) {
       $('form').submit(); // form should be selected as DOM element or form id or form class like: $('.fomaClass') or $('#formId')
    }
  });
</script>
```

Refer [check_box API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) form set value in a checkbox, So when you submit the form you will get the value.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into mine, but nothing happened when I checked the 5 checkboxes. Thanks for the thoughtful answer tho :)

Comment: debug the on change event of checkbox and verify that you are able to get the DOM's form element for submitting the form.

Comment: Nothing happened means what? Are you not able to submit the `form` or not getting the `values` of `checkbox` after submitting the `form`?

Comment: form is not submitting.

Comment: I am able to submit with codyeatworld's answer, but only 1 of the 5 is saving to the database.

Comment: Yes sir. And I used it with @codyeatworld's version too `$(document).on('click', 'input[name="inspiration[check]"]', function() {`

Comment: Btw I meant to say codyeatworld's answer not rosuandreimihai's answer